# getting the value inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to get the name attribute while it is in the while loop?
I want to call the name attribute of the radio button to insert to database

```
if ($result = $conn - > query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result - > fetch_row()) {
        //$app_rows.append($row[1])
        $app_rows = array($row[1]);
        ?>
        < tr >
            < td id = "app_name" > <? php foreach($app_rows as $values) {
                echo $values; ?> < /td> < td > < input type = "radio"
                name = "<?php echo $values; ?>"
                id = "<?php echo $values. " - P0 "; ?>"
                value = "P0" > < /td> < td > < input type = "radio"
                name = "<?php echo $values; ?>"
                id = "<?php echo $values. " - P1 "; ?>"
                value = "P1" > < /td> < td > < input type = "radio"
                name = "<?php echo $values; ?>"
                id = "<?php echo $values. " - P2 "; ?>"
                value = "P2" > < /td> < td > < input type = "radio"
                name = "<?php echo $values; ?>"
                id = "<?php echo $values. " - P3 "; ?>"
                value = "P3" > < /td> < td > < input type = "radio"
                name = "<?php echo $values; ?>"
                id = "<?php echo $values. " - P4 "; ?>"
                value = "P4" > < /td> <? php
            } ?>
            < /tr> <? php
    }
    $result - > close();
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify what you are looking for?

Comment: a way to get the value of every radio outside the while loop

Answer (score 1):

you can use array in attribute name, 
eg in your code

```
<td> <input type="radio" name="radioVal[]" id="<?php echo $values. "-P0"; ?>" value="P0"></td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="radioVal[]" id="<?php echo $values. "-P1"; ?>" value="P1"></td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="radioVal[]" id="<?php echo $values. "-P2"; ?>" value="P2"></td>
```

then in backend

```
$radioVal = $_POST['radioVal'];
if(count($radioVal)!=0){
$radioIsVal = '';
for ($i=0; $i < count($radioVal); $i++) { 
 $radioIsVal .= $radioVal[$i].',';
}
$radioIsVal = rtrim($radioIsVal ,',');
// $radioIsVal the value is P0, P1, P2
}else{
echo 'no radio value';
}
```

may it can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result = $conn->query($query))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_row())
    {
        $app_rows = array($row[1]);
        echo"<tr>";
        foreach($app_rows as $values)
        {
            echo"<td id='app_name'>".$values."</td>";
            for($c=0;$c<=4;$c++)
            {
                echo"<td> <input type='radio' name='".$values."' id='".$values.'-'.$c."' value='P".$c."''></td>";
            }
        }
        echo"</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but how will i be able to get the name attribute of the radio button outside the while loop? im going to insert it to my database

Comment: Hey @winter your question is little bit not clear. Do you want to get Name attribute to be inserted in database or wants it corresponding value to be inserted in database? Also you said you want it outside of while loop, do you mean to insert those into database as soon as your while loop completed or do you have a some kinda form which is submitted? and that time you want to save it into database?

Comment: @adaptable.services i need to get the corresponding value to be inserted in database. i dont know what to put in the post method so i can insert it to database

Comment: display the data from db and set it to table as radio button ,when click on submit ,php get the value of the client choose . right ?